# How can I give a key in JSX the value of a variable depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, key, jsx

I'm learning React by implementing a front-end interface for the note app API that I created. I have succeeded in having a list of all the note titles in my database appear. I want to be able to click on a title and have the note expand into the text of the note. The easiest way I've found for this is to give the "key" attribute of the 'li' as a variable and to also declare the same variable in the JSX { } object because they have the same name.

I've been looking for an answer for this for a few days and have been unable to find this exact problem. You can put a variable in a normal JSX expression but I need to do it on the 'li' which means technically in the HTML.

Here's some code to understand what I'm saying.

```
const NoteData = () => {
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //AXIOS CALL
      setTitles(response.data[0]);
    });
  }, []);
  //^^^^^add the array there to stop the response.data from repeating WAY TOO MANY TIMES

  let listTitles = titles.map(titles => (
    <li className="noteTitles" key={titles.title}>
      {titles.title}
    </li>
  ));

  let showText = titles.map(titles => (
    <li className="openText" key= {titles.text_entry}>
      {titles.text_entry}
    </li>
  ))

  let openNote = () => {
    setOpen(open => !open);
    if (open) {
      return (
        <div className="noteContainer">
          <ul onClick={openNote} className="titlesList">
            {showText}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (!open) {
      return (
        <div className="noteContainer">
          <ul onClick={openNote} className="titlesList">
            {listTitles}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
  return { openNote };
};

export default NoteData;
```

That is the code I currently have. Here's showing a more simplified version of the openNote function that maybe makes more sense and shows what I'm trying to do:

```
VariableHere = "";

  let openNote = () => {
    setOpen(open => !open);
    open ? (VariableHere = titles.text_entry) : (VariableHere = titles.title);
  };

  let listNotes = titles.map(titles => (
    <li className="noteTitles" key={VariableHere}>
      {VariableHere}
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <ul onClick={openNote}>
        {listNotes}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

On click of each element there should be a switch of the key elements so if the element is 'open' the key variable and given variable in the JSX object should be mapped to titles.text_entry and on '(!open)' the key and JSX should be mapped to titles.title.

Comment: do your note items have a unique id?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo yes in the API database they have unique ids

Comment: Gotcha! See my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you're using a ternary in a weird way:

```
open ? (VariableHere = titles.text_entry) : (VariableHere = titles.title);
```

Ternaries are meant to be expressions whose value is conditional, but you're using it like a shorthand if/else. Try something like

```
VariableHere = open ? titles.text_entry : titles.title;
```

which is both shorter and more readable.

Second of all, keys in an array of elements are meant to help React determine which elements to update, if an item represents the same object, its key shouldn't change. In this case, regardless of what you're displaying, an item in the array represents the same note. Always using the title as the key should be fine provided items can't have the same title. If they can, use some sort of unique ID instead. If the order of the items doesn't change throughout the life of the component, using the array index as the key is fine.

Lastly, what you seem to want to do is called "conditional rendering". There are many ways to achieve this in react, one such way is to use the pre-cited ternary operator. Here is a minimal working example:

```
  const listNotes = titles.map(note => (
    <li className="noteTitles" key={note.title}>
      {open ? note.title : note.text_entry}
    </li>
  ));

  const openNote = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  }

  return (
    <div className="noteContainer">
      <ul onClick={openNote} className="titlesList">
        {listNotes}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
```

You could also use a ternary in the key expression, but as I talked about above, it's not a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data-structure, I think you can simplify your code a bit. There is no need to create separate arrays for titles and contents. It sounds like you just want to expand and collapse a note when it is selected.

Here is a really simplified version on how you an do this. I'll use a sample data-set since we don't have access to your API.

```
const NoteData = () => {
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState([]);
  const [currentNote, setCurrentNote] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    //AXIOS CALL
    // setTitles(response.data[0]);
    let data = [
      { id: 1, title: "a", text_entry: "what" },
      { id: 2, title: "b", text_entry: "is" },
      { id: 3, title: "c", text_entry: "up?" }
    ];
    setTitles(data);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = noteId => {
    let selectedTitle = titles.find(title => title.id == noteId);
    //"collapse" if already selected
    if (noteId === currentNote.id) {
      setCurrentNote({});
    } else {
      setCurrentNote(selectedTitle);
    }
  };

  let listTitles = titles.map(title => (
    <li
      className="noteTitles"
      key={title.title}
      onClick={() => handleClick(title.id)}
    >
      {title.title}
      {title.id === currentNote.id && <div>{title.text_entry}</div>}
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      Click on link item
      <ul>{listTitles}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-silence-366ne

**The main updates**:

1. You don't need to have an `"open"` state. To be more succinct and
   accurate, you should have a `currentNote` state instead, which is
   set when clicking on a list item.
2. Have your `handleClick` function accept a `noteId` as an argument.
   Then use that `noteId` to find the corresponding note in your titles
   state. Set that found note as the `currentNote`. If the selected
   note was already the `currentNote`, simply set `currentNote` to an
   empty object `{}`, thus creating our expanding/collapsing effect.
3. In the JSX, after the title, use a ternary operator to conditionally
   display the `currentNote`. If the note being mapped matches the
   `currentNote`, then you would display a div containing the
   `text_entry`.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm piecing through this answer now and taking your advice into account :) I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Hi @Lisonallie any updates on getting this to work :)

Comment: Hi @Christopher Ngo ! I used the solution below to do what I want and I'm going to combine your solution with how to match the ids/titles afterwards :) but first trying to get the basics of the app to work

Comment: Sounds good! @Lisonallie let me know if you have any questions :)